# Invalid downloaded file name on MS Edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I have some problem with MS Edge 20.10240.16384.0 (the newest versions has the same error).
I'm trying to download file with JS (clear JS, I have no opportunity to use any libraries). Here is the way I'm doing this:

```
window.open(url);
```

Where url variable is an URL to file which I want to download. Opening that URL instantly causes file download. The problem is that the downloaded file has no extension and it's name looks like

`'=_UTF-8_B_dGVzdEZpbGVOYW1lLV9kc2FkLnBkZg==_='`

The original file name is `'test.pdf'` and my method works perfect with Chrome, Firefox and IE11.
Are there any solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: Alex, I am an engineer on the Edge team and would love to look into this more closely. Can you provide a URL that reproduces the issue? I'll gladly investigate the differences between Edge, IE, Chrome, and Firefox to see if we ought to modify our present behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow to fix that error in MS Edge. We can do something stupid like this.

[image]

I don't know about the your server's programming language. So I simply post you a flow-chart about it for you to implement it.

Here's a client code:
(I am sorry that I used a library (jQuery))

```
var uid = "12093ujdskf3";
var url;
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: "http://www.example.com/download.jsp",
  data: {
    uid: uid
  },
  error: function(){
    url = null;
  },
  success: function(data){
    url = data.url;
  }
});
if (url == null){
  alert("Error occurred!");
  return;
}
window.open(url);
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the `test.pdf` result that @Alex ask

Comment: Indeed. As I understand it, " =_UTF-8_B_dGVzdEZpbGVOYW1lLV9kc2FkLnBkZg==_= " is the file name result, not the input URL.

Comment: Just edited the answer. However, no clues to find the actual file name from the url.

Comment: I've found the solution. It's base64. So I need modify server side code.

Comment: @Alex You should better state you are able to modify server side code. I just though that that "file name" is a unique id, which requires the client to send a request to the server to get the actual url.

Comment: @Alex Just modified the answer to a probably acceptable answer. You can try my method above.

Comment: @mob41 I'm an engineer on the Edge team and I'd love to know why you "hate Edge". What can I (and my team) do to improve?

Comment: @Sampson I should better remove "hate Edge", as I just want to express that "I like using Chrome instead of Edge". Sometimes Edge is bit slower that Chrome.

Comment: @mob41 Thank you for the honesty :) We're aiming to improve each and every day. If you wouldn't mind, I'd love to know which scenarios you find are particularly painful in Microsoft Edge. Any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Took me a good few hours and found out that if file name has '£' character, the file gets download as txt with random characters as the file name.

Added code in the API to replace '£' with 'GBP' for the file name.
File download works perfectly fine now.

Weird thing is that I check all characters against Path.InvalidPathChar() list provided with System.IO.File class. Yet '£' throws an error. And that's also why I couldn't get the issue right away as I know '£' is an allowed character.

File download tested with ASP.Net MVC WebApi.
Both IE and Edge keep failing but Chrome and Mozilla works without an issue.